# Prove the general linear group is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, metric-spaces

I was wondering if somebody could help me with the following problem.

Let $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ identified in the standard way with a subset $E(n^2)\cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

I was thinking of defining a map , sending every real $n \times n$ matrix to its determinant, but I'm entirely sure this works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Question: Prove that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ with the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, is not connected

Comment: Sounds like a good start. Where do you think there may be problems in that approach?

Comment: I'm really not sure! If we define $f:M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ,where $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices and $f$ takes each matrix to its determinant. Then surely $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}})=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: OK, thanks! I was just a bit thrown by the $E(n^2)$ bit to be honest. Thanks for the swift replies!

Comment: How would I prove that it is not connected? Find a disconnection? Maybe define two sets, one containing invertible matrices with positive determinants and the other with negative determinants?

Comment: Again a good start. What property of continuous maps and connected sets could be useful?

Comment: The map sending a matrix to it's determinant is continuous. So if we restrict $f$ to $f: GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$. Then since $f$ is continuous and surjective, $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$ which is  disconnected implies that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected?

Comment: It does indeed. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ is a disconnection?

Comment: I mean why $f$ being continuous and surjective, and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ being disconnected implies that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected.

Comment: I think I can assume that the determinant map is continuous and I have a lemma from lectures stating that if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and surjective, then X connected implies Y is connected. So I took the contrapositive?

Comment: Yes. Of course you can also directly say that $U^- = \det^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ and $U^+ = \det^{-1}((0,+\infty))$ are two disjoint nonempty open sets with $U^- \cup U^+ = GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. But assuming that the determinant map is continuous is not good. _Why_ is it continuous?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, is it because it is a polynomial? Or because the pre-image is open?

Comment: "Polynomial" is excellent. At a point where you discuss connectedness, it's a rather safe assumption that the continuity of polynomials as maps $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is known. So "As a polynomial in the coefficients of the matrix, $\det$ is continuous" ought to be sufficient.

Comment: Do you know how I could show that the function $f: GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ given by $f(x):=x^{-1}$ is continuous? I was thinking of using the fact that $A^{-1}=\frac{Adj(A)}{det(A)}$, but I'm not sure. Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: That works. You need to say why that shows continuity, of course.

Comment: Well the determinant is continuous, so if I can prove that the $adj(A)$ is also continuous then I'm done by algebra of continuity. But how do I prove that $adj(A)$ is continuous?

Comment: A matrix-valued function is continuous if and only if the component functions are continuous. What are the components of $\operatorname{Adj} A$?

Comment: $Adj(A)_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}A_{ji}$ where $A_{ji}$ is the $(i,j)$ minor of $A$ i.e. The determinant of the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained by deleting row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: And thus it is continuous because …?

Comment: It's a polynomial!?

Comment: Right. Polynomials to the rescue once more ;)

Comment: Haha! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The same argument for matrix multiplication right?

Answer (score 2):

To show that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open in the space of all $n\times n$ matrices $E(n^2) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, your idea is good:

The determinant

$$ \text{det}: E(n^2) \to \mathbb{R} $$

is continuous because for any matrix $A\in E(n^2)$, $\text{det}(A)$ can be written as a polynomial in the entries of $A$. We have

$$ GL(n,\mathbb{R}) = \text{det}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}), $$

and since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open in $E(n^2)$.